# Shortcut for multiple search criteria

Tags: php, sql

I have a search form with 3 text box for user to enter.

```
Keyword text box
Name text box
Date text box
```

Right now i have to make 6 "if" to caters user selections.

Is there any way i dont have to make so many "if"?

example code if user choose to have all 3 text box filled :

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE keyword=<keyword txbox> AND Name = <name txtbox> AND Date = <date txtbox>
```

Comment: If this is what you are doing, you are leaving yourself wide open to SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Dale M: why do you think so? It's fairly easy to implement what OP wants without vulnerabilities

Comment: I just trying to make it simple, i do of course put prevention step such as escape query. The question is there any way to simplify the steps without going through so many IF statement

Comment: @Genjo: an array with white list of column names. Then you check if the column from another row is there and add it to the query

Comment: What if i have combine AND / OR together? Example
keyword textbox OR Name txtbox and vice versa.

Comment: Not sure, but do you mean `MATCH ... AGAINST`?

Comment: What's wrong with a couple of if blocks anyway?  You only have to write them once and if they support your business requirements, do it.

Comment: @Dan Bracuk: copy-paste is wrong, that's what

Answer (score 0):

raw example,  no sanitisation:

```
<?php
$op=array('keyword','name','date');
$_POST=array('keyword'=>'a','name'=>'b','date'=>'c');

    $q="SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE ";

foreach ($op as $o){
    if(!empty($_POST[$o])){
    $q.= $o.' = "'.$_POST[$o].'" AND '; 
    }

}

$q=substr($q,0, -4);


echo $q; // SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE keyword = "a" AND name = "b" AND date = "c" 
?>
```

Comment: minor: single quotes, major: for newbies questions it's a must to add escaping

Answer (score 0):

This construct will get you down to 3 if blocks.  I don't write php so others can give you the syntax.

```
select somefields
from sometables
where 1 = 3
and 
(
if they filled out the keyword
or keyword = that variable
if they filled out the name
or name = that variable
if they filled out the date
or date = that variable
)
```

Make sure you use query paramters.  Also make sure you have a plan for when no text boxes are completed.  Finally, if the date field includes a time component, deal with it in your query.

Comment: That's what I said about - copy-paste. Such code is error prone and difficult to maintain